# How to Combine Data when Columns are Different in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to have a master file that contains data from 3 separate sheets. Each sheets has the same first 5 columns in order but 3 other columns are in different order in the 3 sheets. How can I combine the data when columns are located differently into one master file?

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I have shared a screenshot in my post. So what I have now is 3 sheets with data imported from other spreadsheets. These 3 sheets is the main files for the categories called assignments, group and lomfcu. Within this 3 main sheets, 6 columns has the same placing and order of headears. But in the mapping 3 other hearders has different columns in the respective 3 main sheets. Now trying to figure out if using query I can use to pull the data. I am using this right now =Query({QA_Assignments_2021!A2:AB;QA_Group_2021!A2:AB;QA_LOMFCU_2021!A2:AB},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6")

Comment: hi @AizatSheikhAbdullah, either of the answers below should be able to solve your issue. Were you able to check them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

player0 already provided a great idea of how you will solve your issue. If you are doing it right, it should look like the formula below:

```
=Query({
Query(QA_Assignments_2021!A2:AB, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,I,N,H");
Query(QA_Group_2021!A2:AB, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,T,L,R");
Query(QA_LOMFCU_2021!A2:AB, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,Y,H,S")
}, "where Col1 is not null")
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- The three `A2:AB` can be simplified into `A2:N`, `A2:T` and `A2:Y` respectively since you don't need the columns beyond that. But either of the two should work. Adjust the ranges and columns to be queried accordingly if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

you can rearrange columns in `{}` array:

```
=QUERY({
 {QA_Assignments_2021!A2:H};
 {QA_Group_2021!A2:F, QA_Group_2021!H2:H, QA_Group_2021!G2:G}; 
 {QA_LOMFCU_2021!A2:H}}, 
 "where Col1 is not null")
```

or you can do it with multiple queries like:

```
=QUERY(
 {QUERY(QA_Assignments_2021!A2:H, "select A,B,C,D,E,G,H,F");
  QUERY(QA_Group_2021!A2:H,       "select *");
  QUERY(QA_LOMFCU_2021!A2:H,      "select A,B,C,H,G,E,F,D")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue recently but was able to work it out by using Col1,Col2,Col3 instead of using A,B,C:

```
=Query(Importrange("sheet link", Tab name!A:AZ),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3.Col10 Where Col1 is not null",0).
```

It is to extract data from different sheets and combine them in one as a master sheet.